# What devices would help me track my outdoor activities and fitness?

Tags: hiking, trails

I recently moved to CO and I want to buy a device to help me track various activities such as hiking, trail running, snowboarding, etc. Along with the general "outdoor activities", I also want to use it for going to the gym as well for basic fitness tracking.

While fitness/outdoors is my primary concern, I'd like it to also look stylish and not too bulky.

Comment: What do you actually need it for? We'll need more info to help you make a good decision here

Comment: Hi Eric, and welcome to TGO.SE. This question is a bit confusing as it stands... it might be _too broad_ (give me all the input you can think of), or it could be a duplicate of "[How to select a good GPS receiver?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4045/how-to-select-a-good-gps-receiver)", or it could be flagged as a _shopping question_. As Liam pointed out, we need more information to see how we can help.

Comment: Like beeing said, it's too broad, opinion based and a shopping request. I vote to close.

Comment: I apologize if you believe it's too broad as I have fairly broad criteria since I'm wanting to use it for multiple items. Trailing running and general hiking are my top 2 criteria. So elevation/distance are key for that. Outside of hiking, I want to use it for general running on tracking calories to miles to time and as well as basic in gym use. On a side note, I like the idea of the maps within the Fenix 2 as I plan to start doing a lot more backpacking and off trail hiking.

Comment: This has to be opinion based, I'm afraid. Even your comment re the Fenix 3 being "obviously" the best is an opinion. As it happens, I disagree. It might not even be the best for £250, and there are some much better above that.

Comment: How can a GPS possibly track fitness in a gym?

Comment: @gerrit [Activity tracker counts steps, calories and distance; vibration alert motivates you to move when you've been sitting too long; sleep mode monitors your quality of rest](https://www.rei.com/product/884614/garmin-fenix-3-gps-watch?cm_mmc=aff_AL-_-114239-_-136055-_-NA&avad=136055_cc4799ff)

Comment: @JamesJenkins Sounds like it does a whole lot more than a GPS.

Comment: @Rory - You are correct. Based off what I've read the Fenix 3 and Suunto Vertical are some of the higher rated ones for around the $500 US mark. I am trying to stay lower than that which is why I'm looking at previous years models and was just curious about people's experience using those products.

Comment: I wonder if this question is looking for a product recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you get an inexpensive smart phone instead?  For less then $100 (currently some are less than $30) you can get a smart phone at tracfone.com that will do all of that and more. Pair it with a fit bit and still be around $100

Comment: Smartphones are not suitable for backpacking due to limited battery life, in particular if the GPS is switched on all the time, which you want if you want to have a track log.

Comment: @gerrit Is the battery life of a GPS watch better then smartphone?

Comment: GPS watch, I don't know.  But my handheld Garmin lasts 70+ hours with ultimate lithium batteries.

Comment: @gerrit, needs differ of course, but I've use my smart phone and  GPS software to log a track on 4-7 day backpacking trips. I do pause the tracking while I'm in camp, and I do bring along an extra battery which weighs 4oz. On the other hand, I can also use it to listen to music in the evening, and it is a backup light source.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Hmm, ok.  I thought smartphones typically lasted only a day on a battery.  Maybe it's less bad than I thought (I used six lithium AA batteries on my recent 17-day backpacking trip).

Comment: @gerrit, I think the key is to put the smart phone in 'airplane' mode. The GPS still functions, but it stops the phone from fruitlessly looking for a cell connection. There are also several settings in my GPS software to minimize battery use.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant you might want post your comment here as an answer to this question http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13980/when-considering-gps-battery-life-where-are-the-best-options

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a notebook and a pencil. Excellent battery life, works well in all weather, backup options somewhat limited though.